# flowplayer mp4 not working over https

Tags: https, mp4, flowplayer

I have flowplayer set up and have encoded an mp4 using h264.  When I run locally (http) the video plays great.  When I run on our development server (https) flowplayer shows a black screen and plays the audio, but never shows video.  FLV files work fine over https.  How can I get the mp4 to work?

UPDATE:  I just tried in safari and it played the mp4 fine over https.  It is not working in firefox over https.